# hierarchical records using sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, hierarchical-query

I have a table like this

```
**id    exType               exId   depType              depId**    
  1     Ceo                  1      Board Of Director      1    
  2     Board Of Director    1      Manager                4    
  3     Board Of Director    1      Manager                5    
  4     Manager              4      TeamLead               1    
  5     Manager              5      TeamLead               2    
  6     TeamLead             1      Member                 7    
  7     TeamLead             1      Member                 8    
  8     TeamLead             1      Member                 9    
  9     TeamLead             1      Member                 10   
  10    TeamLead             2      Member                19
```

I want all the member's when i give input as exType as Manager and  exId as 4 i want

```
                                    Member                 7    
                                    Member                 8    
                                    Member                 9    
                                    Member                 10
```

or I want all the member's when i give input as exType as teamlead and  exId as 1 i want

```
                                    Member                 7    
                                    Member                 8    
                                    Member                 9    
                                    Member                 10
```

or or I want all the member's when i give input as exType as CEO and  exId as 1 i want

```
                                    Member                 7    
                                    Member                 8    
                                    Member                 9    
                                    Member                 10
```

Comment: . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursive query to exhibit all dependents of a given node:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select depType, depId 
    from mytable 
    where exType = 'Manager' and exId = 4
    union all
    select t.depType, t.depId
    from cte c
    inner join mytable t on t.exId = c.depId and t.exType = c.depType
)
select * from cte
```

Comment: @David: the syntax for recursive queries sligthly varies across databases (and it might depend on the database version too). In which database/version do you want to run this?

Comment: currently its for Oracle (11)and MySql(5.7) databases

Comment: @David: mysql supports recursive queries starting version 8.0 only. In oracle, small changes are needed. You can't really have a recursive query syntax that woks in all databases. You tagged your question `postgres`, so I provided a solution for this particular database.

Comment: thank u, it would be helpful if u could provide for both databases (Mysql/Oracle)